# Order list: Pay unpaid invoices

Tags: views, commerce, payment-gateways

I have created some extra statuses: Paid and Unpaid.

Now they got the functionality and react on the transaction balance perfectly fine. However, on the user site, it is kind of a dumb thing.

Even if the invoice is unpaid, there is no option to pay the invoice from the user --> orders pages. It looks like you can ONLY pay at checkout; apparently you cannot pay with Paypal later on.

Either way, I am looking for the function that users can pay the amount (or remaining amount) using Paypal WPS. Can any one help me accomplish this?

Secondary, as small addition to this, I would love the user to be able to see transactions that have been done AND the open balance (if any) similar to what the Admin view got.

Can anyone help me accomplish these 2 points? I am not a coder so please keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask joachim about the status of [this module](http://drupal.org/node/1250924). He's very good and was interested in finishing it up a little over a month ago. I'm not certain where he is but it's worth a try.